# Configuration class - Get configuration array from the function string argument

Tags: php, arrays, singleton

I have a function like this:

```
$conf = array ('test_value' => 1, 'test_value2' => 2);
function GetValueArray($array, $value)
{
     return $array[$value];
}
```

Im using this function to receive a value from an array. My problem is that i cannot use this function like this:

```
GetValueArray('conf', 'test_value');
```

How could i convert 'conf' to the real array named conf to receive my 'test_value'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because functions have their own scope, be sure to 'globalize' the variable that you're looking into.

But as Rizier123 said, you can use brackets around a variable to dynamically get/set variables.

```
<?php

$conf = array ('test_value' => 1, 'test_value2' => 2);

function GetValueArray($array, $value)
{
  global ${$array};
  return ${$array}[$value];
}

echo GetValueArray('conf', 'test_value'); // echos '1'
echo GetValueArray('conf', 'test_value2'); // echos '2'


?>
```

Comment: Just to note that here, that in PHP 7 the brackets in: `${$array}[$value]` won't be necessary any longer

Comment: You literally saved my life! Thank you!