# How to assign value to global variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have a global variable like

```
<?PHP
function PrintVariable($str){
   global ${"check" . $str} = "some value";
   echo  $checkmap;    
}
 PrintVariable('map');
```

but I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\PHP\index.php on line 3

after removing the `global` from the code everything work fine but I have to create `global` at this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no combined "declare global and assign value" statement in php.
You'd have to do that in two steps, e.g.

```
<?php
function foo($str) {
    global ${"check" . $str};
    ${"check" . $str} = "some value";
}

foo('bar');
echo $checkbar;
```

...but what you really should do is: avoid globals.

Comment: Thanks VolkerK and is it still global?

Comment: @MonaCoder Yes it is global. + You could use the `$GLOBALS` array, then you can assign it in one statement

Comment: As the sample demonstrates: $checkbar can be accessed outside of `function foo()`, so yes, the function sucessfully polluted the global namespace....

Answer (score 3):

With the "**global**" keyword, you can only reference a variable, not set the value of it.

Your code would be:

```
<?PHP
function PrintVariable($str){
   global ${"check" . $str};
   ${"check" . $str} = "some value";
   echo  $checkmap; // outputs: some value
}
PrintVariable('map');
echo  $checkmap; // outputs: some value
```

See:

http://php.net/language.variables.scope

[Configuration class - Get configuration array from the function string argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640424/configuration-class-get-configuration-array-from-the-function-string-argument/32640527#32640527)

Comment: Thanks Christopher_Johns  and is it still global?

Comment: It is still global. You can call it (outside of the function) as **$checkmap** just as if it were set as a normal variable.